# How to force static linking with MSBuild

Tags: c++, msbuild

I have C++ project that is configured by using CMake for producing Visual Studio 2017 project files (.vcxproj) that are then used for building using `MSBuild` from the command line. The project uses a pre-compiled library with both dynamic (.dll) and static (.lib) libraries. My attempt to build has always produced a dynamically linked executable. How can I force `MSBuild` to use static libraries (.lib)? Are there any command line flags that need to be passed to `MSBuild` for this?

Comment: Are you sure that your library has static (.lib) library that is not just an import library?

Comment: @VTT, the static library (.lib) is also built along the course the same build process.

Comment: But you've wrote "The project uses a pre-compiled library with both dynamic (.dll) and static (.lib) libraries."

Comment: If a *single* project and configuration is creating a `.lib` and `.dll` at the same time, the `.lib` is almost certainly only an import library for the DLL, and not a standalone static library. Normally the static library is set to be built using a different configuration (E.g. a project might have a `Debug Static` and `Debug DLL` or similar configuration names). Linking to the "static" import library will always result in needing the DLL at run time, it doesn't actually contain the code.

Comment: Yes, by pre-compiled I meant the static libraries are built first before the executable. Infact these are two different projects with a single Python script that configure and build one after the other by calling CMake and MSBuild.

Comment: Don't you have to tell CMake to create a static library (i.e. `add_library(mylib STATIC ${MYSOURCES}`), instead of MSbuild?